# Simple_form many-to-many association method not displaying proper labels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, simple-form

I'm having a problem with displaying my many to many association with simpleform.
I have a Shop model, Product model, and a ShopProduct model that connects them all together.
So `shop - shopproduct - product
If i use in my form:

```
<%= f.association :shop_products, as: :check_boxes%>
```

i get this code

```
    <input checked="checked" class="check_boxes optional" id="shop_shop_product_ids_2"
 name="shop[shop_product_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="2">  
    #&lt;ShopProduct:0x007f59d47b6be8&gt;</label>
```

if i use  `label_method: :product_name` i get an error
`undefined method`product_name' for #<_ShopProduct:0x007f59d474dff8>`

How can i display normal info in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's my mistake, You shouldn't target model that acts as connection. you should use the needed model:
`<%= f.association :shops, as: :check_boxes,label_method: :name  %>`